# Overriding __setitem__ in Python dict subclass doesn't work for setting values of items inside

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I'm trying to create a class that will deal with my custom file type in Python. I want it to act exactly like a dictionary, so I extended the built-in `dict` class, adding open (actually `__init__`) and save functions. The structure is as follows:

```
{
  'A': [
    [1, 'Doe', 'John', '49396928593', '0', '23', '20'],
    [2, 'Smith', 'Mark', '05926836832', '0', '6', '14'],
  ],
  'B': [
    # and so on
  ]
}
```

So it's basically a dictionary of lists of lists.

Now I'd like to have a class variable, `changed` which wolud be automatically set to `True` when anything is changed in the object. Apparently, `__setitem__` of my class is fired only when items directly in the dictionary are changed. Is there a way to catch any change of my dictionary's sub-items?

Here's my code:

```
import zlib
import json

class MRK(dict):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.changed = False

        fp = open(path, "r")
        compressed = fp.read()
        fp.close()      
        json_data = zlib.decompress(compressed)
        data = json.loads(json_data)
        super(MRK, self).__init__(data)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print "!"
        self.changed = True
        super(MRK, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def save(self):
        json_data = json.dumps(self)

        compressed = zlib.compress(json_data)
        fp = open(self.path, "w")
        fp.write(compressed)
        fp.close()


f = MRK('dane.mrk')

for c in f:
    print c

    for std in f[c]:
        if std[1]=='Smith':
            std[1] = 'Brown'
        print std

print f.changed # outputs False

f.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not; you'll have to use custom list objects for those and propagate the 'changed' flag up to the parent dictionary or use a central object to track changes.

Once you retrieve an object from a dictionary, the dictionary itself has nothing to do with it anymore; you could store that object in a separate reference and pass that around without the original dictionary being involved, for example.

The other option is to always require an explicit set on the object again:

```
lstobj = yourdict['A']
lstobj[1][1] = 'Sue'
# explicit set to notify `yourdict`
yourdict['A'] = lstobj
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. Now I wonder if it's really worth the effort of if I should maintain this flag manually.

Comment: You could look at the ZODB persistence packages as they also have to track changed objects. `PersistentMapping` and `PersistentList` are custom implementations that'll set a changed flag on `self` and a central manager will then commit changes to the ZODB, with which they are registered.